# org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException exception in cassandra 2.2.4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

We are working on MySQL to Cassandra Data Migration. We dumped MySQL data into CSV format and converted it to Cassandra CSV  and used encoding UTF-8. When we import Cassandra CSV it works fine for one cluster. But for the same CSV file it throws following exception in another cluster for same Cassandra Version (2.2.4)

```
message="org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Invalid UTF-8 bytes 56bc71d9">
Aborting import at record #5. Previously inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be present as well.
```

It shows exception for different records all the time. Record numbers and byte values are not consistent.

We used below command to import CSV file

```
copy <TABLE> FROM <FILE> with DELIMITER = '\t' AND NULL = 'NULL' AND QUOTE = '\"' AND ESCAPE = '\\';
```

We checked for some solutions but most of them have suggested 'ASSUME' command. As we are using Cassandra 2.2.4 we do not have Cassandra-Cli to check the command.

Is there any suggestion to check out the issue or any possible cases this issue may happen.

Comment: Is there any external plugin with cassandra ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, we used cassandra-lucene-index 2.2.4.1 (compatible with Cassandra 2.2.4 ) for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a issue about it in cassandra lucene index 2.2.4.1, that i have submitted.
**They already solved it**.
Just update your lucene index code
The class `com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.service.RegularCellsMapper`
In the method `Columns columns(ColumnFamily columnFamily)`
Add the below code after `for (Cell cell : columnFamily) {`

```
if (!cell.isLive()) {
    continue;
}
```